# No import options in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to import a gradle project into eclipse. However, when I do `File -> Import`, it gives no options.

[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there any messages about this.

Comment: There isn't a .log file.

Answer (score 0):

This can be the result of an issue with the resolution of your display. If you expand the import window - or, presumably, if you change the screen resolution - the options will appear.